# React app on deployment server

Tags: laravel, reactjs, nginx, npm, deployment

I have an Ubuntu VPS with Laravel v5.6 served with nginx, and I am trying to use React on the front-end. I don't know if this is possible what I want to do is:

- use node and npm to build my front-end app locally,
- generate the CSS and JS files and upload those already generated files to my VPS server,
- the output should not change since as far as I know npm generates at JS and CSS files with your whole code in it

Thanks for the help, and if there is any suggestion for a different approach just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should start to use a frontend bundling solution like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [parcel](https://parceljs.org/), they do exactly the same

If you generate your app with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) it comes with webpack built-in